# Vue method executes a large number of times during rendering

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a Vuetify carousel where each slide contains 3 elements in a custom component name `AlbumCarousel`. Each element is an `albumPreview` which represents an album. All albums are declared in the `categorieAlbums` in `data`. I'm using a `v-for` loop to create the carousel items and the `AlbumPreview` components inside.

To make sure I render all albums, I use the method `count` to increment `compteurAlbum` (album counter) to return the right index for the `categorieAlbum` array. In this example, with the sample data, there should only be 2 carousel items of three `albumPreview` components created. So in total, there should only be 6 `albumPreview` components in the carousel. But when I console log the results `compteurAlbum` after each time `count` is executed, the value increments until 605 and I don't understand why.

**EDIT:** I've realized that the `count` method executes 6 times when I remove data manipulation from the `count` method. For example, if `count` only returns 0, it will only be executed 6 times. Is there any explanation for this?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-carousel height="300" v-bind:hide-delimiters="true" interval="60000000" id="categorieCarousel" >
            <v-carousel-item v-for="n in nombreDeCarouselItem" v-bind:key="n">  
                <v-layout justify-center >
                    <v-flex v-for="x in nombreDAlbum"  v-bind:key="x">
                        <albumPreview v-bind:album="categorieAlbums[count()]"  class="CategorieAlbumPreview" />
                    </v-flex>
                    <v-spacer>
                    </v-spacer>



                </v-layout>
            </v-carousel-item>


        </v-carousel>
    </div>



</template>
<script>
import albumPreview from './AlbumPreview.vue'
export default {
    props:["Albums"],
    components:{
        albumPreview
    },
    data(){
        return{
            nombreDAlbum:0,
            nombreDeCarouselItem:0,
            compteurAlbum:-1,
            categorieAlbums:
                    [
                        {
                            id:1,
                            nom:"dsadasdasdas1",
                            link:"https://lasueur.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Koba-LaD-L-Affranchi.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            id:2,
                            nom:"dsadasdasdas2",
                            link:"https://lasueur.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Koba-LaD-L-Affranchi.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            id:3,
                            nom:"dsadasdasdas3",
                            link:"https://lasueur.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Koba-LaD-L-Affranchi.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            id:4,
                            nom:"dsadasdasdas4",
                            link:"https://lasueur.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Koba-LaD-L-Affranchi.jpg"
                        },

                        {
                            id:5,
                            nom:"dsadasdasdas5",
                            link:"https://lasueur.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Koba-LaD-L-Affranchi.jpg"
                        },

                        {
                            id:6,
                            nom:"dsadasdasdas6",
                            link:"https://lasueur.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Koba-LaD-L-Affranchi.jpg"
                        }
                    ]

        }
    }
    ,
    mounted(){
            this.nombreDAlbum=3;//represente le nombre d'albums dans un slide du carousel
            this.nombreDeCarouselItem= Math.ceil(this.Albums.length/this.nombreDAlbum);//represente le nombre de carousel items, 
            //math.ceil pour sassurer davoir 1 carousel de plus que this.Albums.length/this.nombreDAlbum    

            alert("nombreDAlbum "+this.nombreDAlbum+" nombredeCarouselItem "+this.nombreDeCarouselItem);




    },
    methods:{
        count:function(){

            this.compteurAlbum=this.compteurAlbum+1;


            return 0;

            //afin de display tout les albums

        },
        yio:function( hey){
            alert(hey);
        }
    },
    computed:{
        increment:function(){

             //permet de savoir a quelalbum on est rendu afin de le passe au album preview,
            //afin de display tout les albums
            this.count();
            return this.compteurAlbum;


        }
    }

}
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the counting up to 6 isn't a big surprise. The nested loops go through 6 items in total so `count()` is called 6 times.

The difficulty is when you manipulate data inside `count`, like this:

```js
this.compteurAlbum=this.compteurAlbum+1;
```

The right-hand portion reads the current value of `compteurAlbum`. Reading a reactive property value during rendering creates a dependency on it. The left-hand portion then assigns a new value to `compteurAlbum`. This will trigger any dependants on that property, including the rendering of this component. The component will be added to the render queue for the next tick. The rendering that is ongoing in the current tick will still continue but once everything is complete in the current tick it will move on to the next tick and re-render the component. This causes a potentially infinite loop of rendering.

The key section of the Vue source code is here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/78c3ce0ce0c2230f657cb7772a84fc7aa7ce0825/src/core/observer/scheduler.js#L99

Notice two things:

1. In a dev build it will only go round the re-rendering loop `MAX_UPDATE_COUNT` times. That value is 100. That's why you get ~600 extra calls to `count()`. In production it would just keep going.
2. There's a warning logged out, *You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.* You should see that warning in your browser's console log.